# Using a local image with EmbedBuilder

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

According to the Discord.NET [documentation page for the `EmbedBuilder` class](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.EmbedBuilder.html#usage-with-local-images), the syntax (converted to VB) to add a ***local image*** to an `EmbedBuilder` object should look something like this:

```vb
    Dim fileName = "image.png"
    Dim embed = New EmbedBuilder() With {
        .ImageUrl = $"attachment://{fileName}"
    }.Build()
```

I'm trying to use something like this to add a dynamically created image to the `EmbedBuilder`, but I can't seem to get it to work properly. Here's basically what I've got:

```vb
Dim TweetBuilder As New Discord.EmbedBuilder
Dim DynamicImagePath As String = CreateDynamicImage()
Dim AttachURI As String = $"attachment:///" & DynamicImagePath.Replace("\", "/").Replace(" ", "%20")

With Builder
    .Description = "SAMPLE DESCRIPTION"
    .ImageUrl = AttachURI
End With

MyClient.GetGuild(ServerID).GetTextChannel(PostChannelID).SendMessageAsync("THIS IS A TEST", False, Builder.Build)
```

My `CreateDynamicImage` method returns the full path to the locally created image (e.g., `C:\Folder\Another Folder\image.png`). I've done a fair amount of "fighting"/testing with this to get past the `Url must be a well-formed URI` exception I was initially getting because of the `[SPACE]` in the path.

`MyClient` is a `Discord.WebSocket.SocketClient` object set elsewhere.

The `SendMessageAsync` method *does* send the Embed to Discord on the correct channel, but without the embedded image.

If I instead send the image using the `SendFileAsync` method (like so):

```vb
MyClient.GetGuild(ServerID).GetTextChannel(PostChannelID).SendFileAsync(DynamicImagePath, "THIS IS A TEST", False, Builder.Build)
```

the image is sent, but as a part of the message, rather than included as a part of the Embed (*this is expected behavior* - I only bring it up b/c it was a part of my testing to ensure that there wasn't a problem with actually sending the image to Discord).

I've tried using the `file:///` scheme instead of the `attachment:///` scheme, but that results in the entire post never making it to Discord at all.

Additionally, I've tried setting the `ImageUrl` property to a Web resource (e.g., `https://www.somesite.com/someimage.png`) and the Embed looks exactly as expected with the image and everything when it successfully posts to Discord.

So, I'm just wondering at this point if I'm just missing something, or if I'm just doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-posted this to [issue #1609 in the Discord.Net GitHub project](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/1609) to get a better idea of what options are available for this and received a good explanation of the issue:

> The `Embed` (and `EmbedImage`) objects don't do anything with files. They simply pass the URI as configured straight into Discord. [Discord then expects](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message-using-attachments-within-embeds) a URI in the form `attachment://filename.ext` if you want to refer to an attached image.
>
> What you need to do is use `SendFileAsync` with the embed. You have two options here:
>
> Use `SendFileAsync` with the `Stream stream, string filename` overload. I think this makes it clear what you need to do: you provide a file stream (via `File.OpenRead` or similar) *and a filename*. The provided filename does not have to match any file on disk. > So, for example:
>
> ```cs
> var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
>     .WithImageUrl("attachment://myimage.png")
>     .Build();
> await channel.SendFileAsync(stream, "myimage.png", embed: embed);
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can use `SendFileAsync` with the `string filePath` overload. Internally, this gets a stream of the file at the path, and sets `filename` (as sent to Discord) to the last part of the path. So it's equivalent to:
>
> ```cs
> using var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
> var filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
> await channel.SendFileAsync(stream, filename);
> ```
>
> From here, you can see that if you want to use the `string filePath` overload, you need to set embed image URI to something like `$"attachment://{Path.GetFileName(filePath)}"`, because the attachment filename must match the one sent to Discord.

I *almost* had it with my code above, but I misunderstood the intention and usage of the method and property. I guess I thought the `.ImageUrl` property somehow "automatically" initiated a `Stream` in the background. Additionally, I missed one very important piece:

> As it's an async method, you must await (or whatever the VB.NET equivalent is) on SendFileAsync.

So, after making my calling method into an async method, my code now looks like this:

```vb
Private Async Sub TestMessageToDiscord()
    Dim Builder As New Discord.EmbedBuilder
    Dim AttachmentPath As String = CreateDynamicImage()  '<-- Returns the full, local path to the created file

    With Builder
        .Description = "SAMPLE DESCRIPTION"
        .ImageUrl = $"attachment://{IO.Path.GetFileName(AttachmentPath)}"
    End With

    Using AttachmentStream As IO.Stream = IO.File.OpenRead(AttachmentPath)
        Await MyClient.GetGuild(ServerID).GetTextChannel(PostChannelID).SendFileAsync(AttachmentStream, IO.Path.GetFileName(AttachmentPath), "THIS IS A TEST", False, Builder.Build)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Now, everything works exactly as expected and I didn't have to resort to uploading the image to a hosting site and using the new URL (*I actually had that working before I got the response on GitHub. I'm sure **that** code won't go to waste*).

---

#### EDIT

Okay, so I *still* ended up going back to my separately hosted image option for one reason: I have a separate event method that modifies the original `Embed` object during which I want to *remove* the image and replace the text. However, when that event fired, while the text was replaced, the image was "moved" to the body of the Discord message. While I *may* have been able to figure out how to get rid of the image entirely, I decided to "drop back and punt" since I had already worked out the hosted image solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everyting I could, but I got stuck at the same point at where you are now.
My guesses are that Discord doesn't like the embedded images from https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments, and only accepts the new files from https://media.discordapp.net. I might be wrong though, this is the way it worked for me.

I believe it's only a visual glitch, as I found if you send a link for an image from cdn.discordapp.com/attchments in your regular Discord client, it bugs out and shows an empty embed for some reason.

That would make sense since the default link used in an embedded image actually starts with https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/...

You could solve this issue by using https://media.discordapp.net, but it seems like Discord.net is configured to use the old domain.

Comment: Thank you, @akac - It sounds like, at least for now, if I want to use "purely" the Discord.NET library, I may want to try and figure out a way to upload the images to a separate Web resource (e.g., [ImgBB](https://imgbb.com/), [imgur](https://imgur.com/), [imgbox](https://imgbox.com/), etc.), retrieve the generated URL, and use *that* for the `ImageUrl` property. I suppose I could also look into overloading that property in my own code, but something like this might be more useful in the long-term.